# Iterate through array to construct hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Currently I have:

```
cache_hash = {}
array = [:id, :content, :title]
data_source = some_active_record_object
array.each{ |k| cache_hash[k] = data_source.send(k) } 
cache_hash
#=>{:id=>"value1", :content=>"value2", :title=>"value3"}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to iterate through the array and get the hash out.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I know it's not fair to select a rails specific answer. But I do appreciate the lesson from @Arup too.

Comment: No, it was completely fair, as you tagged it with ruby-on-rails and therefore a Rails answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to follow this route, but here is an alternative with AR query:

```
Foo.select('id, content, title').to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)
```

`Foo` is the model you're operating on.

Comment: That's very interesting. Since I'm targeting only one object, not an array, here is what I ended up with: `data_source.serializable_hash(only: [:id, :content])`.

Answer (score 4):

Write as below :

```
cache_hash = Hash[array.map { |k| [k, data_source.send(k)] }]
```

Or use new [`#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

```
cache_hash = array.map { |k| [k, data_source.send(k)] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [@Arup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22596858/456814) using `map`. The cool thing about `map` functions, in any programming language (not just Ruby), is that you can also express them in terms of
an `inject` function (also called `fold`, `reduce`, or `aggregate` in other languages):

```
cache_hash = array.inject({}) do |hash, key|
  hash[key] = data_source.send key
  hash
end
```

Not as clear as Arup's answer using `map`, but kind of cool to know anyways.